# How to observe powerline modulated signal?

Tags: power-line-communication, frequency-measurement

I was assigned to observe the modulated signal of a PLC modem, but I have not really started yet. How do I do this? Should I use an oscilloscope or spectrum analyzer? If so, do I just connect it to the power line where the PLC modem is connected?

Comment: What protocol/frequencies does it use?

Comment: you will probably need some kind of filter to separate the signal from the mains 'signal' - observing a signal of a few volts riding on top of a 50 or 60Hz, 120 or more volt sinusoid will be nearly impossible

Comment: @gervy, did you ever do this successfully?

Answer (score 5):

You didn't give the all-important information about what frequencies you are using for the communication.  You can't know if a filter is right if you don't know what frequencies you want to separate.

However, the main point is to attenuate the power line frequency by a large factor.  Here is one simple passive way to do that:

[image]

This is a simplistic filter which is basically 4 high pass filters strung together.  I'm assuming the communication frequency is high compared to the power frequency, like 100 kHz or more.  Each high pass filter stage has a rolloff of 1.6 kHz.  60 Hz is far enough below that so you can make the approximation it will be attenuated by 1.6 kHz / 60 Hz = 27.  These filter stages will interact some to give more overall attenuation, but even ignoring that you get at least the single filter stage attenuation to the power of the number of filter stages, or about 495 k in this case.  That means the 120 V 60 Hz power signal will be down to less than 240 µV out of this filter.  100 kHz, which we're assuming is your lowest frequency of interest, is 63 times the high pass filter rollof frequency, so won't be effected much by this filter.

The signal directly out of this filter is not ready for running into a chip like a opamp or microcontroller A/D yet.  The power line has all kinds of nasty noise on it, with some transients that can be a few 100 V.  This filter will pass such short term spikes, which would blow up a opamp or microcontroller.  There needs to be some sort of clamping function, keeping in mind that those component have to be able to handle 100 V or more for a short time.

The voltage rating of the filter components needs to be carefully considered too.  C1 will take most of the 60 Hz voltage, and certainly needs to be rated for power line operation.  Even after just the first stage, the 60 Hz voltage will be low enough to not be a problem for ordinary resistors.  However, the resistors need to be able to handle the temporary high voltage spikes that won't be attenuated by the filter.  Either get resistors rated for a few 100 Volts, or implement the resistors shown in the schematic by 3 or 4 ordinary equal resistors in series.

Comment: the modem transmits the signal using wavelet OFDM.operating frequency is at 2-30MHz do i use the same value? and if i plug the oscilloscope at the end of the said filter will i be able to see the signal already? thanks alot

Comment: @Gervy: Since the filter above was designed to reduce 60 Hz to low levels and pass 100 kHz with little attenuation, it will certainly pass 2 MHz with effectively no change.  It will load high frequency signal with 2.5 kOhms, but in my experience the power line only has a few 10s of Ohms impedance at 1 MHz, so that shouldn't be a problem.  You could use lower cap values and reduce 60 Hz even more without effecting 2 MHz much.  For example, 1 nF sets the individual HPF rolloffs at 16 KHz, 265x above 60 Hz and 126x below 2 MHz.

Answer (score 3):

You're saying little (nothing!) about the protocol. Is this Ethernet Over Powerline? The protocol matters because of the frequencies used.

Powerline communication both has a much higher frequency and much lower level than the 50/60Hz mains power. The higher frequency has its limitations: mains wiring isn't really fit for it, and the signal radiation will cause much attenuation over longer distances.
On the other hand the higher frequency makes it easier to separate the signal from the power. You definitely need insulation, and then transformers are an option. Not ideal, because not only will they scale the signal as much as the mains voltage, a common mains transformer's inductance will attenuate the signal (though the transformer's capacitance may provide better coupling, I'm not sure how this balances).

Instead of a transformer you can also insulate through capacitors. These have to be safety capacitors. Couple one capacitor from the phase and one from the neutral to the inputs of a difference amplifier. The capacitors will block most of the low frequency 50/60Hz power, but since the level of this low frequency is so high (120/230V) you'll need a notch filter to get rid of it.

A spectrum analyzer will not make you much wiser, you'll just see at what frequencies communication occurs. Which you probably know. A scope will allow you to watch the signal in the time domain.

Comment: sorry for the lack of info.yes it is ethernet over powerline. the modem is using HD-PLC standard. it is operating at 4-28MHz and uses wavelet OFDM modulation. well i have read in some article that i only need to use a spectrum analyzer with a voltage probe and plug it in the same powerline network where the powerline modem is connected then i will be able to see the transmitted signal of the plc modem, i am not sure of this though

Answer (score 1):

OK I got a Hantek 5102P hooked to a 100:1 Cat II high voltage probe on channel one. I got a TP-Link Powerline network running and I hooked the 100:1 probe ground wire first to the single phase 230 volt line's ground wire. Then I located the Neutral wire for the power line circuit and hooked the 100:1 channel 1 probe to this neutral wire.

Then you have to set the channel 1 vertical control to 200 mV millivolts volts/div. Then set the Horizontal sec/div to 20 ms milloseconds.
Now you need to fire up the youtube video and watch the traffic of your signal at around 200 kilohertz but it varies. You will see that when your youtube video sends a lot of audio data that the scope will show an immense amount of waves in bursts of data. This is the essence of the wave modulation. Then if you go into FFT math function of the Hantek 5102P you will see that the Flattop wave analysis chart shows a very wide set of frequencies that are modulated upward during the data bursts. You can hit the F7 button on the Hantek to show both the FFT Spectrum Analysis and the normal scope volt/time waves simultaneously in a split dual screen of two graphs.

Even though the TP-Link sends the data over both the Load and Neutral lines of your home wiring AC lines, an oscilloscope can only pick out a signal from a fairly quiet line so trying to see this hi freq modulation on the Load line of your home powerlines at 110 or 230 Volts is like trying to listen to your heart beat at a AC/DC rock show. Best to go and stick the probes of the scope on the Neutral return lines of the home and wack the horizontal and vertical adjustments to find the signal in the wee 200 Khz ranges.

Bon Hantekin'